# Yet Another Issue With Form Validation

Tags: jquery, validation, jqueryform

Ok I am doing my best to learn jquery through Test and Practice. I know there are sme perfect libraries out side to Validate Forms but I would like to learn it by myself at least for now!
I have a Form in [this Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Proweb/xG54A/) and I am getting error on validating the Form. As you can see I have two simple inputs Email and Username Now what I am trying to do is checking whole inputs at [image]First Step is to see if there are any empty inputs or not, if so jquery will generate error messahes (which is doing now)[image] Then I would like to add some validators filed by field to check all inputs and here I am getting issues 
First of all the code in fact is not validating the input ,also is adding the Error Message to the other input as well! and Finally even after entering correct inputs the form in not submitting!

Here is the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var email = $('form #email').val();
$('#myform').submit(function() {
        var abort = false;
        $("div.err").remove();
        $(':input[required]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val()==='') {
                $(this).parent().after('<div class="err">This is a Requierd Field</div>');
                abort = true;
            }
            else{
                if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
                $(this).parent().after('<div class="err">Email Not Match</div>');
                abort = true;                                         
               }
            }
        }); 
        if (abort) { return false; } else { return true; 
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the 'Email Not Match' problem change this -

```
else{
  if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
    $(this).parent().after('<div class="err">Email Not Match</div>');
    abort = true;                                         
  }
}
```

To this -

```
else{
  if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
    $(email).parent().after('<div class="err">Email Not Match</div>');
    abort = true;                                         
  }
}
```